# Retail Transaction Service Cache

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aot

I wrote some methods in Class `RetailTransactionServiceEx`, called them from `Application.TransactionService.InvokeExtension` method at POS, then I needed to do some changes in one of my methods in `RetailTransactionServiceEx`, but changes did not reflect, then for troubleshooting purposes I renamed my method name, but POS through error method not exists in class, I generated Incremented CIL, Full CIL, restarted AOS service, restarted my POS but it still said method does not exists.

Then I went home, and came next day at work, I found my method is working from POS, so the question is that why did it took a whole night ? I did not shut down my computer. Is there any sort of cache system and how do we clear it for quick reflection of our changes in Transaction service classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset IIS.
open windows power shell and execute "iisreset" command
It worked for me. 
though i don't know what happened at night, you can check the event viewer.